# R.id.imageView1 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I checked my entire code in java file there is no import. android.R and xml starts with 'a' **activity_main**.

I even rebuild the project.
But I'm unable to understand why the id **imageView1** cannot be resolved.

Comment: Post directory structure and xml file please.

Comment: post you layout xml and activity code

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Activity` in other package than main package you must implement

```
import com.example.your.path.to.project.R
```

Comment: i donot have like that its a new android project i have generated, where both belong to the same package. but still not resolved.

Comment: Do you use Android Studio?

Comment: And also i cannot post my xml file images/screenshots because i need reputation points which i lack . Thank you

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/firstscreenimage"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/vjitimage" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Edit your question rather than posting in comment

Comment: Try clean project. Maybe you have incompatibility sdk version or you don't use app compat v7 or v4 ?